# New User.employeeId ExtensionProperty not working

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Recently in our tenant appeared a new `employeeId` attribute to the `user` entity.

We have over 40k user accounts; some of them created as pure Azure AD Users and others as Mail Users (via Exchange Online).

For many accounts, attempting to `POST` to the `employeeId` fails with the following error:

> Unable to update the specified properties for objects that have originated within an external service.

We have tried with Microsoft Graph (`/Beta`), Azure Graph API (`v1.6`) and via the AAD v2 PowerShell module.

Answer (score 0):

Is this user being synchronized from on-premises (using AD Connect)?  If so then most of the properties for the user are mastered in on-premises AD and cannot be changed/updated in the cloud. You need to update this property in the on-premises AD (and it'll sync).

**UPDATE**: Sorry for the late response. The issue was that for cloud-only users that were created through Exchange (like Exchange PowerShell) meant that these users are "marked" as created by Exchange.  For some properties, like `employeeId`, this can mean that that particular property can only be updated by the creating service (Exchange).  This makes sense for things like email addresses and proxyaddresses that Exchange provides and is the owner for - but doesn't make sense for `employeeId`.

I believe this issue is **now fixed** and it has been rolled out to Production.  I have been able to do a rudimentary validation for this by:

1. Creating a cloud-user using Exchange PowerShell, and
2. Updating the newly created cloud-user's `employeeId`, using a PATCH operation in Microsoft Graph preview /beta endpoint. This step is now successful (rather than throwing an error)

Please let us know if this is now fixed for your scenarios.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Hi, actualy no, there is no on-premisses available. It is a pure-Cloud solution with no AADConnector in place!.
These users were created with New-MailUser command via PoSH EXO to support coexistence with Lotus Notes during migration from on-premises.
Now all new users (for new employees) are provisioned as User Accounts directly in AzureAD and seem having no issues.

Comment: Can you provide the full error response please - with the client-request-id and timestamp please, and we'll take a look.

Comment: REQUEST
************************
PATCH /<tenant-id>/users/<object-id>?api-version=1.6 HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 75
Authorization: Bearer <OAuth2-token-Base64>
Host: graph.windows.net
Content-Type: application/json

{"employeeId":"<employee-id>","objectId":"<object-id>"}


RESPONSE
************************
{"odata.error":{"code":"Request_BadRequest","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Unable to update the specified properties for objects that have originated within an external service."},"date":"2017-11-15T18:29:46","requestId":"971a0615-da03-4ba9-886c-ff36183bd888","values":null}}

Comment: How will this impact cloud-only identities such as those created with Managed Service Identity? Would we need to use a cloud-only group?

Comment: Is this still an issue?  employeeId is GA in Microsoft Graph, and setting this on cloud-only users should be possible.I was able to add an employeeId to a cloud only user